# Does this distribution relation have a name: $\mathbb E(X^n)=b^n \mathbb E(Z^n)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

More precisely, if $X$ and $Z$ are distributions so that $X=bZ$, then
$\mathbb E(X^n)=b^n \mathbb E(Z^n)$. I found it on [this site](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Weibull.html#baspdf1) and would like to know "where it comes from".

Comment: Is it different from linearity of expectation?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I mixed up something in my previous comment, that's it, thanks.

Comment: In the case of finite discrete random variable: $E(X^n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_i\cdot x_i^n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_i\cdot (bz_i)^n = b^n \sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_i\cdot z_i^n = b^n \cdot E(Z^n)$ IN the other cases the argument is similar ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $Z$ is a random variable in the probabilistic space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and $X=bZ$then, $$\int_\Omega X^ndP=\int_\Omega b^nZ^ndP=b^n\int_{\Omega}Z^ndP$$.

Thus $E[X^n]=b^nE[Z^n]$.